# Dirac Orthonormality Proof - Can't Make Sense of Complex Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, quantum-mechanics, orthonormal

I'm having trouble rationalizing  a particular statement that is, surely, present in many quantum mechanics textbooks. The following statement comes from the orthnormalization condition for eigenfunctions of the wavefunction,  $\Psi (x, t) $, subject to the momentum operator, $\hbar/i (d/dx)$, with REAL eigenvalues, $\lambda \in R$. The eigenfunctions are of the form:

$\psi_\lambda = e^{i \lambda x / \hbar} $

and then, taking their inner product

$ < \psi_\lambda' | \psi_\lambda >  =  |A|^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i (\lambda - \lambda')x/\hbar} dx = |A|^2 2 \pi \hbar \ \delta(\lambda - \lambda')  $

So I'm quite unclear about that last part. Of course, if $\lambda' \neq \lambda$ , you are integrating a sinusoid, and the answer is zero, however, isn't:

$ \left. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i (\lambda - \lambda')x/\hbar} dx \right|_{\lambda = \lambda'}  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1 dx  = \infty $

I mean, $ e^{i (\lambda - \lambda')z/\hbar}$ is analytic everywhere, so you could just complex integrate, treating i as a constant and take limits, (same answer, no?). I also thought about Cauchy's Integral Theorem, and doing a contour integral, and using the maximum modulus principle:

$ \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \left. \int_{-p}^{p} e^{i (\lambda - \lambda')x/\hbar} dx \right|_{\lambda = \lambda'}  = 2 \pi \sum_i f(z_i) - lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} p \left| e^{i(\lambda - \lambda') p / \hbar} \right| $

where $z_i$ is the location of singularity i. However, as far as I can tell...there are no singularities, and the term on the right is unbounded, ( $\rightarrow \infty$). So why does that evaluate to the delta function?

Thanks

Comment: The integral doesn't exist in the classical sense. It is just an imprecise notation for the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution. The Fourier transform of $1$ term is a Dirac distribution, multiplication with an $e^{ixt}$ term gives a translation under the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see a delta function, you should always understand any equation, identity or expression in a distributional sense, which means that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\lambda')\delta(\lambda-\lambda')d\lambda'=f(\lambda)$$

for any sufficiently smooth $f(\lambda)$.

Now

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\lambda')\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i (\lambda - \lambda')x/\hbar} dx d\lambda'$$

is, provided the integrations can be exchanged,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\lambda x/\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\lambda')e^{- i \lambda'x/\hbar} d\lambda' dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\lambda x/\hbar}\tilde{f}(x/(2\pi\hbar)) dx = 2\pi\hbar f(\lambda) $$

where I successively applied [the Fourier transform and the inverse Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

Comment: Very good, that's what I was missing, I just glazed over the fact that you can neatly throw a delta function integral over either $\lambda$ or $\lambda'$ and have it be equal to the same integral, a la your second statement. Thank you sir.